# Windows 10 under VMWare 11 caches MAC address

Tags: networking, vmware, mac-address, windows-10-preview

I have VMWare Workstation 11 and network for VMs configured as NAT. DHCP configured manually so every VM has fixed hostname and IP address.

I've installed Windows 10 TP to one of the VMs. Then I turned the VM off and copied .vmdk files to another VM (duplicated VM). Then I turned the second VM on and I expect it will get appropriate IP and MAC. But I observe that old MAC (from the first VM) was kept, so IP address is incorrect as well. So that's the issue I observe, looks like MAC address is being cached somewhere in the system.

One can disconnect and connect network adapter - it solves the problem, after reconnecting MAC address changes and VM gets appropriate IP address. But I would like to have it changed automatically after turning it on.

There was no such issue in Windows 7, 8, 8.1, so I believe it's about Windows 10 and\or VMWare.

Can you please advice me how can I clear "cache" or force Windows to get new MAC address?

Comment: I have Windows 10 RTM and I observe the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found good solution, so I've applied a simple workaround - create restart_network.bat script and put in to startup (shell:startup)

Here is the script content. Several network interfaces are required because I've faced the issue when Windows treats network as a different network after deploying VM image to another server, so the system gives name "Ethernet 2" instead of "Ethernet".

```
@echo off 

netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disabled
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" disabled
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 3" disabled
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enabled
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" enabled
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 3" enabled
```